# How SimpleImputer works to replace nan values in a dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I have a ndarray of shape(10,3) that contains some missing values(nan). I want to replace missing values with mean value of respective columns. I have used SimpleImpueter for this. My code is as follows:

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values = 'nan',strategy='mean')
```

This code is not working and showing following value error:

```
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

Any suggetion to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write `imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values = 'nan',strategy='mean')`, you are actually telling scikit learn to replace all occurrences of the string `'nan'` by the mean of the column. This is not what you want here, instead, you want to replace the `np.nan` object with the mean (which happens to be default).

So, simply using `imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values = np.nan,strategy='mean')` or

`imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy='mean')`

instead should work.